# Does rain affect VFR criteria?

Tags: safety, visual-flight-rules, uk

Does rain affect VFR criteria? In other words, if visibility is 1500m or more and you are in sight of the surface, but there is heavy rain, can you still fly VFR?

[Here is an example](https://youtube.com/shorts/NZaZGUX4CF8?si=kUxpE9O6hIne9hnM) of the conditions I'm asking about.

Comment: Was visibility really 1500m inside of that rain shower?

Comment: 1500 metres of visibility is a lot worse than you might think! The visibility is definitely greater than 1500 metres in that video

Comment: @quietflyer I believe so. The focus of the camera was on the raindrops on the windshield, so it is hard to judge the visibility because everything further away than a couple of meters was blurred anyway.

Comment: @DeltaLima: In the video we can see a horizon, and tree outlines on the ground.  If visibility was really that low, wouldn't you not see a horizon?  (Or maybe that's just a nearby ridge or edge of a forest they're flying towards.)

Comment: @PeterCordes don't get me wrong, I think the visibility was well over 1500 m. It is the out-of-focus camera that may give the impression that visibility was bad. OTOH, in heavy  rain ,cameras give sometimes a better visibility that what you see out of the window.

Comment: @DeltaLima: Gotcha.  (I took your "I believe so" as agreeing with the OP that the visibility really was 1500m, as the answer to quietflyer's question, rather than agreeing with the implicit doubt of that claim which I guess you must have meant.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rain or no rain is not a factor for meeting the legal definition of VFR minimums.

However, at those minima, which is roughly 1 mile/clear of cloud in North America, it is dangerous.

I would fly in those conditions as a bush pilot, say at 500 AGL and a mile vis and a 600 ft ceiling, rain or no rain, but that was over wilderness, on routes that were well known (no towers), on floats where I can put it down on a lake within 5 minutes of flying in any one direction, and I still considered it dangerous and stressful.

Down south in civilization, with radio masts, and now that wind turbine blight everywhere, forget it. If I was forced down below 1000 ft by that kind of weather in the UK or Southern Ontario, I'd be biting my nails.

If you are at 1000 ft and have 3 miles, light rain like that is not too much a problem, as long as you are aware of the issues like visual distortions (objects out front look lower than they are with rain on the windshield) and the nearly saturated air's carb icing tenedency.

Biggest thing is the "spread". Temperature and dewpoint. Bottom line: what is the risk of it closing in on you? Rain tends to reduce the T/D spread to a few degrees.

The temperature ***trend*** becomes a big factor. Flying in the morning in those conditions, visibility is likely to improve as the ambient temperature rises. Not too bad.

In the afternoon, watch out, as the 3 deg spread at 2pm drops to a 1 degree spread by 4 or 5, and any more decrease than that, boom, you're in fog. If you see wisps of cloud starting to form at your level, in late afternoon, you are in big trouble.

Comment: Well, I know of case where a sailplane pilot was forced to land out on a highway due to sudden *snow* showers greatly reducing visibility.  I was flying nearby but managed to maintain enough vis to make it back to the airport.  Was a ridge-soaring situation.

Comment: Yeah snow showers WAY worse. Late in the season that would be a problem in NE Ontario and conditions that would give 3 mi in rain would give 1 mi in snow.  If you are forced to scud run in settled areas and there is a big highway going your way, get right over that and stay there. At least no towers.

Answer (score 6):

Not directly, however heavy rain will tend to reduce visibility, and obviously you need a certain visibility to remain VMC.